# Proving $A_{ij}=\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}} \det A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

The problem is stated in the title. Here, $A_{ij}$ denotes element $ij$ in the adjugate matrix of $A$, and $a_{ij}$ denotes element $ij$ in matrix $A$. I did the following

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}} \det A = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}} \left( \sum_i a_{ij} A_{ij} \right) = \sum_i A_{ij},$$

which is not what I was supposed to prove. Where is my argument wrong and how would I prove this statement? Thanks!

Comment: If you write explicitly $\sum_i a_{ij}A_{ij}$ you will see that your RHS expression is erroneous.

Comment: Aha! The correct way would be: $\frac{\partial(a_{1j}A_{1j}+a_{2j}A_{2j}+...+a_{ij}A_{ij}+...)}{\partial a_{ij}}$ which then would obviously be $A_{ij}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first equality was wrong because of a conflict of notations on $i$.

$$
\frac{\partial(\det A)}{\partial a_{ij}}= \frac{\partial(\sum_ka_{kj}A_{kj})}{\partial a_{ij}}=A_{ij}.
$$

Comment: OP: Sorry, I edited my answer too late, you already had understood!